# Build loopback 3 project

Tags: node.js, deployment, build, loopback, bitbucket-pipelines

I have loopback 3 project. I want to build it. I am creating a bitbucket pipeline for this.

So for deployment, I want to know how to build loopback 3 project so that I can use these commands into my bitbucket.yml file.

I checked the documentations but for lb3 there is nothing for building the project. I got this into documentations: [Preparing-for-deployment](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Preparing-for-deployment.html). But I am not user how I can use this into the yml file.

For loopback 4 we can use [@loopback/build](https://loopback.io/pages/en/lb4/readmes/loopback-next/packages/build/), and its working fine there. But I couldn't find anything for loopback 3.

Is there any other way to build loopback 3 project ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find anything for creating bundle for my loopback 3 app,
we can't make bundle of lb3. we can run server.js file and that's what I did using PM2. AZURE_EXTENSION_COMMAND here you can see that I have pulled to code from  my branch and run the server.js file from that.
I used following things into my bitbucket.yml :

```
> pipelines:  
      branches:
    >     master:
    >       - step:
    >          script:
    >            - npm install
    >           
    >            - npm run posttest
    > 
    >       - step:
    >          name: Deploy to master
    >          deployment: production
    >          script:
    >            - echo "Deploying to master"
    >           
    >            - pipe: microsoft/azure-vm-linux-script-deploy:1.0.1
    >              variables:
    >                 AZURE_APP_ID: '<appid>'
    >                 AZURE_PASSWORD: '<pass>'
    >                 AZURE_TENANT_ID: '<tenantid>'
    >                 AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: '<rg>'
    >                 AZURE_VM_NAME: '<vm name>'
    >                 AZURE_EXTENSION_COMMAND: 'cd <path to my folder> && git remote add origin <my repo> && git pull origin master && npm install -g npm && npm install && sudo -E pm2 start server/server.js'
```

And in my package.json I have used below script for auditing:

```
 "scripts": {
     "posttest": "npm run lint && npm audit --audit-level high"
  }
```

And it is working fine.
I am not sure if this is the very right methode, but i just found it useful.

Hope it can help someone as well.

Thanks!

Comment: The question and the answer are not related, this is not a solution.
At least this is not the right solution, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't build a loopback 3 server you can only run it.
To run a loopback server you simply use `npm start` or `node .` or even `node server/server`

Your postest script is running a linter and an audit, not the actual server.
What is running your server is not the script in the package.json it's the **AZURE_EXTENSION_COMMAND** part.
It's running `pm2 start server/server.js` which is a process manager that run your node server.

Using pm2 is correct making a separate step for testing and lining is also correct the problem is that you are confusing which part do what role.
This resulted in a response to the wrong question.

Comment: who said my posttest running my server ??

I have used posttest for auditing. And what you said is what I have done. I have pulled the latest code and run the server file. Then whats wrong in question and whats wrong in answer??